# Hide/reveal different forms from button click | Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, show-hide

I am displaying three separate forms based on which one of three buttons is clicked at the top of a webpage. When I refresh the page, all three forms show, one under the other. When I click 'one,' the first (shortest) form shows alone fine, but if I click 'two' or 'three,' everything disappears underneath the buttons. Only the 'one' form is showing whenever I click that button, and I'm not sure how to make 'form two' or 'form three' show on their own with their respective button clicks.

I have included my html and python (as these forms send information to a python script that will take the form inputs as user inputs to run).

custom.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fill out one of three forms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style2.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/materialize/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    <link href="../static/materialize/css/materialize-social.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />


    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#one").click(function() {
          $("#one_animal").show();
          $("#two_animals").hide();
          $("#three_animals").hide();
        });
        $("#two").click(function() {
          $("#one_animal").hide();
          $("#two_animals").show();
          $("#three_animals").hide();
        });
        $("#three").click(function() {
          $("#one_animal").hide();
          $("#two_animals").hide();
          $("#three_animals").show();
        });
      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <h5 style="color:white">How many animals do you want to include?</h5>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <button id="one" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">1 animal</button>
        <button id="two" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">2 animals</button>
        <button id="three" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">3 animals</button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- ONE ANIMAL FORM -->

    <form id="one_animal" action="/form_input_one" method="post">

      <h5 style="color:white">What species are you looking for?</h5>
      <div><input type="text" name="species" style="color:white">

        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </form>



    <!-- TWO ANIMAL FORM -->

    <form id="two_animals" action="/form_input_two" method="post">

      <h5 style="color:white">What species are you looking for?</h5>
      <div><input type="text" name="species" style="color:white">

        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <h5 style="color:white">What second animal are you looking for?</h5>
        <input type="text" name="second_species" style="color:white">


        <h5 id="second_species2" style="color:white">Is there something about this second animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </form>


    <!-- THREE ANIMAL FORM -->

    <form id="three_animals" action="/form_input_three" method="post">

      <h5 style="color:white">What species are you looking for?</h5>
      <div><input type="text" name="species" style="color:white">

        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>


        <h5 style="color:white">What second animal are you looking for?</h5>
        <input type="text" name="second_species" style="color:white">


        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this second animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <h5 style="color:white">What third animal are you looking for?</h5>
        <input  type="text" name="third_species" style="color:white">


        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this third animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="third_features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="third_features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="third_features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </form>

  </body>

  </html>
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/form_input_one', methods=['POST'])
def form_input_one():
    species = request.form['species']
    features = request.form['features']
    return 'First species? %s <br/> Features? %s <br/> <a href="/">Back Home</a>' % (species, features)

@app.route('/form_input_two', methods=['POST'])
def form_input_two():
    species = request.form['species']
    features = request.form['features']
    second_species = request.form['second_species']
    second_features = request.form['second_features']
    return 'First species? %s <br/> Features? %s <br/> Second species? %s <br/> Second features? %s <br/> <a href="/">Back Home</a>' % (species, features, second_species, second_features)

@app.route('/form_input_three', methods=['POST'])
def form_input_three():
    species = request.form['species']
    features = request.form['features']
    second_species = request.form['second_species']
    second_features = request.form['second_features']
    third_species = request.form['third_species']
    third_features = request.form['third_features']
    return 'First species? %s <br/> Features? %s <br/> Second species? %s <br/> Second features? %s <br/> Third species? %s <br/> Third features? %s <br/> <a href="/">Back Home</a>' % (species, features, second_species, second_features, third_species, third_features)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/custom.html")
def custom():
    return render_template('custom.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Additional note: I have tried 'extending' the shortest form with additional fields when the user requests another animal, instead of creating three separate forms. But I keep getting bad requests sending the form inputs to the python script (since hidden fields are considered not filled in when I submit a one animal form with two and three fields still hidden, for example).

These are some questions and resources I have researched that have gotten me to this point:

[Passing input from html to python and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677564/passing-input-from-html-to-python-and-back)

[flask handle form with radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662681/flask-handle-form-with-radio-buttons)

[Flask Error: “Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689195/flask-error-method-not-allowed-the-method-is-not-allowed-for-the-requested-url/20689328)

[w3schools: jquery_hide_show](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show)

Plus a handful of other "how to hide/show elements with JS" before I decided to go with three separate forms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the problem mainly with the forms showing/not showing or is there a request error problem too? Can you please make the question more specific?

Comment: The problem is the forms showing/not showing. Specifically clicking 'button one' shows 'form one' just fine. Clicking either 'button two' or 'button three' causes everything below the buttons to vanish, when I would like the page to display 'form two' or 'form three' respectively. I hope that clarifies, thanks for the comment.

Comment: See my answer below. I closed the div tags and included the code in the answer. Don't forget to upvote if it helped, or else let us know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 div tags that are not closed at

```
<div><input type="text" name="species" style="color:white">
```

Code is working after closing the tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fill out one of three forms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style2.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/materialize/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    <link href="../static/materialize/css/materialize-social.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />


    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#one").click(function() {
          $("#one_animal").show();
          $("#two_animals").hide();
          $("#three_animals").hide();
        });
        $("#two").click(function() {
          $("#one_animal").hide();
          $("#two_animals").show();
          $("#three_animals").hide();
        });
        $("#three").click(function() {
          $("#one_animal").hide();
          $("#two_animals").hide();
          $("#three_animals").show();
        });
      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <h5 style="color:white">How many animals do you want to include?</h5>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <button id="one" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">1 animal</button>
        <button id="two" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">2 animals</button>
        <button id="three" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">3 animals</button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- ONE ANIMAL FORM -->

    <form id="one_animal" action="/form_input_one" method="post">

      <h5 style="color:white">What species are you looking for?</h5>
      <div><input type="text" name="species" style="color:white">

        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button></div>
    </form>



    <!-- TWO ANIMAL FORM -->

    <form id="two_animals" action="/form_input_two" method="post">

      <h5 style="color:white">What species are you looking for?</h5>
      <div><input type="text" name="species" style="color:white">

        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <h5 style="color:white">What second animal are you looking for?</h5>
        <input type="text" name="second_species" style="color:white">


        <h5 id="second_species2" style="color:white">Is there something about this second animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button></div>
    </form>


    <!-- THREE ANIMAL FORM -->

    <form id="three_animals" action="/form_input_three" method="post">

      <h5 style="color:white">What species are you looking for?</h5>
      <div><input type="text" name="species" style="color:white">

        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>


        <h5 style="color:white">What second animal are you looking for?</h5>
        <input type="text" name="second_species" style="color:white">


        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this second animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="second_features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <h5 style="color:white">What third animal are you looking for?</h5>
        <input  type="text" name="third_species" style="color:white">


        <h5 style="color:white">Is there something about this third animal you''re interested in?</h5>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="third_features" type="radio" value="size" />
            <span style="color:white">Size</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="third_features" type="radio" value="sex" />
            <span style="color:white">Sex</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
            <input name="third_features" type="radio" value="color" />
            <span style="color:white">Color</span>
          </label>
        </p>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button></div>
    </form>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: I am also wondering how to keep all three forms hidden when the user lands on the page (right now they're all visible before clicking any buttons), so that a form only appears ONCE a user has clicked on one of the three buttons. I'm still pretty new to Stackoverflow, so I don't know if that warrants a completely new question posted or if it's a quick fix that a comment can take care of?

Comment: you can either add display:none to the css of the forms, or use    $("#one_animal").hide(); for each form in the main $(document).ready(function() { function